# how set selected row in checkbox grid panel extjs depends textfield value

Tags: extjs

i have a grid panel and i want checked the row same as the value of text field. 
anyone can help me.?
this is my code:

```
var check = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({
    checkOnly : true,
    listeners: {
        change: function(checkbox, value) {

            }
    }
}); 
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: "example-grid",
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Group Fields  ',
        value:'a',
        readOnly: true,
        inputId: 'group'
    }]
});

var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Group Fields',
id:'gridPanel',
selModel: check,
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('tes'),
columns: [{
    text: 'Field',
    dataIndex: 'field',
    flex: 1 
}],
viewConfig: {
   markDirty: false
 },
height: 200,
width: 200
});
```

my fiddle example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/y0uzha/f73kx37e/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need one-way binding so I would suggest to apply a **selectionchange** listener to the **selectionModel** to set the value of the groupField. See *grid1#listeners#viewready*. Note: I added an id to the form panel so that you can get a handle on it.

Generally speaking you should not use the id propery on child components, so they can be reusable. It would be better practice to use a viewport or a global parent container that has an id. Also, it would be best practice to use a controller to wire all this business logic together. Enjoy!

```js
var check = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({
  checkOnly: true
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  id: 'formPanel',
  renderTo: "example-grid",
  bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',
  items: [{
    itemId: 'groupField',
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Group Fields  ',
    readOnly: true,
    inputId: 'group'
  }]
});

var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  title: 'Group Fields',
  id: 'gridPanel',
  selModel: check,
  store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('tes'),
  columns: [{
    text: 'Field',
    dataIndex: 'field',
    flex: 1
  }],
  viewConfig: {
    markDirty: false
  },
  listeners: {
    viewready: function() {
      var selModel = this.getSelectionModel();

      //Bind the groupField's value to the selected records 
      selModel.on('selectionchange', function(selModel, selections, eOpts) {
        var groupField = Ext.getCmp('formPanel').queryById('groupField'),
          groupValues = Ext.pluck(Ext.pluck(selections, 'data'), 'field');

        groupField.setValue(Ext.Array.sort(groupValues).toString());
      });

      //Initially selects the first item in the grid
      selModel.selectRange(0, 0);
    }
  },
  height: 200,
  width: 200
});
```

Comment: hi thx for your answer cosbor. but that's not what i mean. i want to check the grid depends the value of the textfield. but in your example code, the textfield follow the check grid value. and when i refresh it the grid always check in a.

Comment: hi i've been found the way. i add this code and it works. `valuetext = document.getElementById("group").value; for (var j = 0; j < valuetext.length; j++) { var index = grid1.store.find('field', valuetext[j]); selModel.select(index, true); }` thx for your help :)

Comment: The textfield is readonly=true so I assumed you just wanted one way binding

Comment: yes, the value of textfield i took from the other page. :) . well how about if i want to fill my combobox in my grid depends the value of textfield.? for example: the value of textfield "a:ASCENDING, c:DESCENDING" . so in row with field "a", combobox is "ASCENDING" and in row "c", the value of combobox is DESCENDING. here is my fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/y0uzha/f73kx37e/25/

Comment: Just add a change listener to the combobox to invoke the sort method on the grid's store